# Java Spring Boot : How to find all rows with multiple Ids like findAllByAge(ArrayList<Long> ageList)?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having a table/entity **User** with fields like userId, name, age etc.

I know with Spring boot, in Repository, we can search for rows like

```
User findByUserId(Long userId)
```

Which may return User with the passed argument user id.

But I am looking for an option where I can pass a list in argument something like below.

```
List<User> findAllByAge(ArrayList<Long> ageList)
```

Which may return all the users with passed ageList. Let me know if this is possible with this or I have to use native query? I know I can do this with native queries also but if it's possible with this then it would be great.

Comment: I often forget how the query method syntax works, perhaps this well help some:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Comment: @Gavin the link is really helpful.

Comment: Anytime.  I didnt know the answer, but had an idea where to look.  Looks like @YCF_L answer below is what you are need, or a very good starting place.  If you are looking to query an age range there is a keyword for that too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `In` in the end of the name of your method:

```
List<User> findAllByAgeIn(ArrayList<Long> ageList)
                       ^^
```

---

For more details refer to this: [**Supported keywords inside method names**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)